# Ajax -- one time per user

Tags: ajax, django, session, post, authentication

I was considering how one would implement some voting mechanism, using AJAX, that limits each user to one vote. On the page you're fetching data from, would you just check the session information, or would you pass the user/pass combo through an AJAX post request?

Any special considerations that need to be taken when the aforementioned is done in django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX requests still honor cookies and will come from the same IP address, so do it server-side, and have your server only accept one vote per IP.  If another vote is posted, make the server simply return a message saying you can't vote more than once.

Comment: Note that this would go entirely in your server-side logic.  You could add client-side code which would display the response text so that the user would know they were being limited, but it's not necessary.

Comment: Great, thanks! I figured it would be safer to use the header, but I wanted to confirm.